# Correct way to use a system constant defined in API level above minSdkValue?

Tags: android

I am trying to use `android.content.ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL` in my application. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL)

I have targeted API level 15 as my minimum however, and this value was added in API level 16.  What is the correct way to get this working?

Can I simply do:

```
public void onTrimMemory(int level)
{
    boolean isCritical = false;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
        isCritical = (level == android.content.ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL);
    }

    // more logic here, regardless of SDK_INT value
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: yes that is what you would do

Comment: this is static final int field ...

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Static final values are inlined at compile time. The value will be there in your code even on lower sdk levels.

Comment: Thank you all very much.  Greatly appreciated!